# Open a JDialog in the middle of the monitor

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

How can I open a `JDialog` completely in the middle of the monitor?

I think I have to do something like this:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
final int height = screenSize.height;
final int width = screenSize.width;
```

But now I don't know how to continue for to reach my target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as for a JFrame or any other Window, you need to `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` after packing it.

```
myDialog.add(everything);
myDialog.pack();
myDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // this centers the window
myDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`public void setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29):

> If the `component` is `null`, or the `GraphicsConfiguration` associated with
>   this component is `null`, the window is **placed in the center of the
>   screen**.

Then you need to.. `myDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`